# How to read macro enabled excel files in R?

Tags: r, excel

I have 2 excel files which have macros in it. The file extension ends with `.xlsb` and `.xlsm`. I want to read these files into R and do exactly what excel is doing with these files in terms of data inputs in R. What is the way to go about it?

For example: if the excel file calculates house prices in sheet 2 based on data input in sheet 1, how can the same results for house price calculation be obtained in R?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at the R package RDCOMClient:

https://github.com/omegahat/RDCOMClient

Here is a nice example shown:

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2021/07/rdcomclient-read-and-write-excel-and-call-vba-macro-in-r/